# Location of embryo development in angiosperms

Tags: botany, reproduction, plant-anatomy

What floral organ does the development of the embryos of angiosperms occurs in? Is it the ovary? The pollen tube grows down through the style and double fertilization occurs and the embryo begins to develop in the megasporangium.